# using column names when appending data in write.table

Tags: r

I am looping through some data, and appending it to csv file. What I want is to have column names on the top of the file once, and then as it loops to not repeat column names in the middle of file.

If I do `col.names=T`, it repeats including column names for each new loop. If I have `col.names=F`, there are no column names at all.

How do I do this most efficiently? I feel that this is such a common case that there must be a way to do it, without writing code especially to handle it.

```
write.table(dd, "data.csv", append=TRUE, col.names=T)
```

Comment: untested, but you could do `col.names = ifelse(ii %in% 1, TRUE, FALSE)` where ii is your loop iteration

Comment: I really don't think this is as common as you think it is. Normally you build the entire data.frame first and then write it once.

Comment: When you are working with large datasets, then building the entire dataframe in memory first might not be an option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may or may not also see a problem with the row names being identical, as `write.table` does not allow identical row names when appending. You could give this a try.  In the first write to file, try `write.table` with `row.names = FALSE` only.  Then, starting from the second write to file, use both  `col.names = FALSE` and `row.names = FALSE`

Here's the first write to file

```
> d1 <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 1:5)                ## example data
> write.table(d1, "file.txt", row.names = FALSE)
```

We can check it with `read.table("file.txt", header = TRUE)`.  Then we can append the same data frame to that file with

```
> write.table(d1, "file.txt", row.names = FALSE, 
              col.names = FALSE, append = TRUE)
```

And again we can check it with `read.table("file.txt", header = TRUE)`

So, if you have a list of data frames, say `dlst`, your code chunk that appends the data frames together might look something like

```
> dlst <- rep(list(d1), 3)                              ## list of example data
> write.table(dlst[1], "file.txt", row.names = FALSE)  
> invisible(lapply(dlst[-1], write.table, "file.txt", row.names = FALSE, 
                   col.names = FALSE, append = TRUE))
```

But as @MrFlick suggests, it would be much better to append the data frames in R, and then send them to file once.  This would eliminate many possible errors/problems that could occur while writing to file.  If the data is in a list, that could be done with

```
> dc <- do.call(rbind, dlst)
> write.table(dc, "file.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. When I try what you suggested I get the following error: Error in write.table(dd, "data.csv", raw.names = FALSE) : 
  unused argument (raw.names = FALSE)

Comment: I did not have a problem with row names initially.

Comment: @user1754606, you get that error because you misspelled "row" as "raw"

Comment: Thank you! perfect, sorry about "raw"/

Comment: it might be better to create a single connection that you pass to `write.table`.  You can leave the connection open until you're done with it, instead of opening and closing every time you write.  See the examples in `?connections`

Answer (score 36):

See `?file.exists`.

```
write.table(dd, "data.csv", append=TRUE, col.names=!file.exists("data.csv"))
```

Thus column names are written only when you are not appending to a file that already exists.

Comment: I wrangled with the accepted answer. This worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the column names of the data frame using `names()` command in R and replace with the same names as existing and then try the `dbWriteTable` command keeping `row.names = False`. The issue will get solved.
e.g.
if your data frame `df1` has columns as `obs`, `name`, `age` then

```
names(df1) <- c('obs','name','age')
```

and then try

```
dbWriteTable(conn, 'table_name', df1, append = T, row.names = F)
```