# How to write CSV with per-variable counts of a data.table?

Tags: r, file-io, count, data.table, plyr

Assuming I have a data table, `td`, with dimensions 1000x4, with column names `x1,x2,x3,x4`. If I do `td[,.N,x1]` I will get the counts for each value of the `x1` variable.

What I would like to do, is to write all these values in a csv in one go,**below each other**, so I try

```
x <- c("x1","x2","x3","x4")
l_ply(x, function(x) {
  write.csv(td[,.N,by=x],file="test.csv") 
}
```

but I get an error:

> The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length .... Each must be
>   same length as rows in x or number of rows returned by i ...

Any ideas ?

Comment: If you are using `write.csv`, then `append = TRUE`, also, may be wrap with `c` i.e. `by = c(x)]`

Comment: Why not perform the calculation first and save to csv in one step? `melt(td)[, .N, list(variable, value)]`

Comment: `write.csv(..., append=TRUE)` fails with *"attempt to set 'append' ignored"*. You have to use `write.table(..., append=TRUE)`

Comment: I rewrote your title to say what you generally want to do, instead of the specific syntax issue.

Comment: Related sub-issue: [Write column header once only, when writing data with write.table(append=T)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462137/using-column-names-when-appending-data-in-write-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `write.table(..., append=TRUE)` because `write.csv()` wrapper doesn't pass it through(!)

Then (and if you don't want a per-variable header before each variable's section, use `col.names=F` ; see [Write column header once only, when writing data with write.table(append=T)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462137/using-column-names-when-appending-data-in-write-table) ):

```
require(data.table)
require(plyr)
x <- c("x1","x2","x3","x4")
td <- data.table(x1=sample.int(2,5,replace=T), x2=sample.int(2,5,replace=T), x3=sample.int(2,5,replace=T), x4=sample.int(2,5,replace=T))

l_ply(x, function(x) {
  write.table(td[,.N,by=x], file="test.csv", append=T, quote=F, row.names=F)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use a `for` loop

```
for(val in x) {
     write.table(td[, .N, by = c(val)], file = "test.csv", append=TRUE)
 }
```

Comment: Doesn't work, `write.csv(..., append=TRUE)` fails with "attempt to set 'append' ignored". If you want to append, you have to use `write.table()`

Comment: @smci mine is `write.table`, i modified it

Answer (score 0):

You can also use rbindlist from data.table:

```
write.csv(
    file = "./tmp.csv",
    x = rbindlist(lapply(x,function(y){
        dt[,.N,by = y]
    }))
)
```