# How to append data with readr::write_excel_csv without repeating column names?

Tags: r, csv, file-exists, readr, write.table

The help file for readr::write_excel_csv suggests the following code usage:

```
write_excel_csv(x, path, na = "NA", append = TRUE,
  col_names = !append, delim = ",", quote_escape = "double")
```

However, **col_names = !append** creates an error.

```
library(readr)
data <- read_csv("col1, col2, col3
a,2,0
b,5,7
c,8,4")

write_excel_csv(data,"data.csv",append = TRUE, col_names=!append)

>Error in !append : invalid argument type
```

Is **col_names = !append** valid code? If not, what does it mean in the context of the help file for write_excel_csv?

col_names = TRUE appends the column names every time. I only want the column names to appear the first time.

**Edit:** At first I thought this code solved the problem, but it doesn't. It works with write.table but not write_excel or write_excel_csv.
[using column names when appending data in write.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462137/using-column-names-when-appending-data-in-write-table/25494328)

```
#!file.exists() works with write.table but not with write_excel or write_excel_csv

#column names appear
write.table(data, "data.csv", append=TRUE, col.names=!file.exists("data.csv"))

#column names don't appear
write_excel_csv(data,"data1.csv",append=TRUE, col_names=!file.exists("data1.csv"))
```

How can I make column names appear the first time but not subsequent times with write_excel_csv?

Comment: Have you tried ```col_names =FALSE```?

Comment: Yes. With col_names=FALSE, column names do not appear. I want the column names to appear the first time, but not subsequent times.

Comment: Does using ```append=TRUE, col_names=FALSE``` correctly append the data to your CSV?

Comment: It correctly appends the data, but does not append the column names. I want the column names to appear conditionally. That is, I want them to appear when the file is first created, but not when I append new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a scope problem with `!append`. R will try to evaluate that statement **before** calling `readr::write_excel_csv`, and if there is no object called `append` in your `.GlobalEnv` it will fail. Even worse, if there happens to be an object called `append` in your workspace, that value will be used in the call, which is almost certainly not what you want. Consider this:

```
f = function (a = TRUE, b = !a) cat("'a' is", a, "; 'b' is", b, '\n')
f()
## 'a' is TRUE ; 'b' is FALSE 

f(b = !a)
## Error in cat("'a' is", a, "; 'b' is", b, "\n") : object 'a' not found

a = FALSE
f(b = !a)
## 'a' is TRUE ; 'b' is TRUE
```

When you call a function, R will first evaluate all statements you provide for the parameters of that function, then make the call with the corresponding values. On the other hand, if you don't provide a parameter that has a default value, that value will be evaluated **within the function's scope**. So when `readr::write_excel_csv()` evaluates the default `!append`, this happens within the scope of the function, where `append` should be defined.

Now, the default value of `col_names = !append` is cleverly chosen to work as you expect, that is to write the headers when not appending, presumably writing a new file. So if you leave it alone and just make the value of `append` conditional it works smoothly:

```
write_excel_csv(data, 'data1.csv', append=file.exists('data1.csv'))
read_csv('data1.csv')

## Parsed with column specification:
## cols(
##   col1 = col_character(),
##   col2 = col_double(),
##   col3 = col_double()
## )
## # A tibble: 3 x 3
##   col1   col2  col3
##   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1 a         2     0
## 2 b         5     7
## 3 c         8     4

write_excel_csv(data, 'data1.csv', append=file.exists('data1.csv'))
read_csv('data1.csv')

## Parsed with column specification:
## cols(
##   col1 = col_character(),
##   col2 = col_double(),
##   col3 = col_double()
## )
## # A tibble: 6 x 3
##   col1   col2  col3
##   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1 a         2     0
## 2 b         5     7
## 3 c         8     4
## 4 a         2     0
## 5 b         5     7
## 6 c         8     4
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I think you are right about what the issue is. The way I coded it, it seemed like R interpreted the file as already existing by the time it evaluated the append argument, even if the file was just being created for the first time.

Comment: Glad to help ;)

Comment: What is the difference between using " " and ' ' as you did above?

Comment: there is no difference as far as I know. I tend to use `' '` only because I save a keystroke. Didn't notice I had used both, i'll edit to avoid confusion. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your data to create a dataframe:

```
data <- data.frame(col1=c('a','b','c'), 
                   col2=c(2,5,8),
                   col3=c(0,7,4))
```

Which produces:

```
  col1 col2 col3
1    a    2    0
2    b    5    7
3    c    8    4
```

Now, I've built an `if` `else` statement that looks to see if the file exists.  If the file does not exist, it will save a new CSV file with the column names included.  If the file does exist, it runs the `write_excel_csv` simply to append new values to the existing columns.

```
if(file.exists("data.csv") == TRUE) {
  # If the file exists, run the append code.
  write_excel_csv(data,"data.csv", append=TRUE)
} else { 
  # If it doesn't exist, save the file with the columns included.
  write_excel_csv(data, "data.csv", append=FALSE)
}
```

If you run the code twice, you will see on the first iteration it will save a new CSV with the dataframe containing the column headers (*assuming you have deleted "data.csv" from your directory*).  The second iteration will simply append the values from the dataframe without column headers, producing:

```
  col1   col2  col3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         2     0
2 b         5     7
3 c         8     4
4 a         2     0
5 b         5     7
6 c         8     4
```